# describe explicitly all the ideals of $R/(f(x))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R := \mathbb R[x]$ be the polynomial ring over the real numbers and $f(x) = x^3 - x^2 \in R$. Describe explicitly all the ideals of $R/(f(x))$ where $(f(x))$ is the ideal of $R$ generated by $f(x)$, by writing each ideal in the form $(g(x))/(f(x))$ for some monic polynomial $g(x) \in R$. which one of them is the zero ideal?

It looks like I should factor out $f(x)$ as $x*x*(x - 1)$ and these are the monic polynomials $g(x)$, is that right?

Comment: It's $x^2(x-1)$.

Comment: you mean the zero ring? but why?

Comment: I am just pointing out a typo in your post. You indeed need to look for monic divisors of $f(x)$. But unless your $f(x)$ was $x^3-x$ rather than $x^3-x^2$, you got the factors wrong.

Comment: oh right, thanks

Comment: but I am not completely sure the reasoning for finding using monic divisor of f(x), could you explain a little bit?

Answer (score 2):

Here’s  Lemma you should be able to prove for yourself:

**Lemma**. If $R$ is a (commutative) ring and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then the ideals of $R/I$ are in natural correspondence with the ideals of $R$ that contain $I$.

Now, the big ring $R$ is $k[x]$, where $k$ is a field (happens that $k=\Bbb R$, but for us now that’s not significant). And $R$ is therefore a principal ideal ring. It follows that the ideals of $R$ that contain $(x^2(x-1))$ are described completely by the elements of $R$ that divide $x^2(x-1)$, up to unit multiples (constant multiples, here).

I think that with this information, you should be able to answer the question.